# What is the internal implementation of mongo update, creating a new document deprecate the existing one or rewrite the existing value in place

Tags: mongodb

When using update or upsert of one document. Internally, does mongo create a new node on disk, deprecate the existing one(like hbase) or actually change the existing record in place?

Answer (score 0):

MMAPv1 engine (now deprecated) was doing in-place updates.

WiredTiger engine uses MVCC (writes a new version of a document).

Comment: Thanks, is there a compaction process running in background to compact the storage?